# htacces некая проблема

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Всем привет , есть htacces в котором написано

```
DirectoryIndex /en/index.php
```

Может кто подсказать как из корня сайта , сделать редирект в папку сайта , уже перебрал кучу правил но не хочет работать ...

Также при добавлении обычно RewriteEngine On в .htaccess . Apache 2 сразу умирает написав Internal Error

```
<Directory /home/afgan/apache2/html>

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

Comment: в `DirectoryIndex` пишется название индексного файла для любой папки, а не путь.

Comment: все решилось , вот только теперь проблема в том что , в адресной строке он тупо показывает 127.0.0.1 , а мне нужно что бы он показывал   в адресной строке 127.0.0.1/en/ возможно ли это через Directory index??

Comment: нет, это возможно через 'Redirect'

Comment: ищу , redirect  , ничего конкретного пока

Comment: Redirect 301 index.php /en/index.php

Comment: но немогу понять одну вещь , если у меня допустим 2 папки /en и /ru 
Я хочу чтобы при открытии example.com открывался по умолчанию example/en , это разве нужно через Redirect делать?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: сделал как написано , в папку /az/

вот что выдает в адресной строку 
http://192.168.0.111/az/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.phpaz/index.php

Comment: вот содержимое Redirect 301 / http://192.168.0.111/az/index.php

Comment: скинь содержимое htaccess

Comment: тогда было Redirect 301 / 192.168.0.111/az/index.php  , сейчас ничего там нет , я добавляю и меняю что бы проверить что работает , в данный момент мне надо что бы при наборе 127.0.0.1 перенаправлялся на 127.0.0.1/az/index.php

Comment: Неужели никто не знает как это сделать , бред какойто , постоянно пишет что İnternal Server error . при попытке задать редирект

Comment: Redirect 301 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1/az/index.php

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: в файле apache2.conf Allow Override = ALL все включено и должно работать 

Вот настройки апача , добавил выше

Comment: проблема еще в том что , как я добавляю RewriteEngine on в .htaccess 

у меня весь апач ломается , и не открывается не одна страница...

Answer (score 1):

Решил Сам , проблема была в следующем.

1 - `sudo a2enmod rewrite` (надо было прописать в терминале)
2 - вот код который заработал.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/az/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/az/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Вот краткая инструкция может кому понадобится еще .

```
1 - /etc/apache2/apache2.conf = AllowOverride All

2 - /etc/apache2/apache2.conf = AccessFileName .htaccess

3 - sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Работает на ubuntu 16.04 
Добавляем в .htaccess RewriteEngine On 
 Если Apache не дает ошибку то .htaccess заработал.

Comment: также помог и вот этот вариант DirectoryIndex /az/index.php